Train Arrival Time Probability Question
So the question states:
At a subway stop there are two trains that stop at the same station. Train A stops every 12
minutes: on the hour, and at 12 minutes, 24 minutes, 36 minutes and 48 minutes after the hour. Train B stops every 20 minutes: at 5 minutes, 25 minutes and 45 minutes after the hour. If someone enters the station at random and takes the first train, what is the probability that it will be an A train?
And the solution attached to the question is:
Consider all of the intervals in which a passenger will be on Train A or Train B.
0 to 5   Train A (5 minute interval)
5 to 12  Train B (7 minute interval)
12 to 25 Train A (13 minute interval)
25 to 36 Train B (11 minute interval)
36 to 45 Train A (9 minute interval)
45 to 48 Train B (3 minute interval)
48 to 60 Train A (12 minute interval)
In all there are 39 minutes of intervals to be on Train A, or 39/60 = 13/20 = 0.65
My question is that if a person walks in and takes the first train, wouldn't it take the next available train? So wouldn't for example if a person walks in at minute 7, it would take Train A rather than Train B because Train A arrives at the minute 12 whereas Train B arrive at minute 25 next?

Well, even the $0-5$ window is wrong, that should be Train $B$.  And the $24$ min $A$ train is ignored.    I think that list needs to be rebuilt.

I didn't make the list, it was provided by an answer key

@lulu Given the apparent (wrong) reasoning behind the answer key, it makes sense to ignore the A at 24 minutes, because when two A trains arrive one after the other, the second train makes no change in the type of train that last arrived. Of course, the initial reasoning is completely wrong, but it is at least consistently applied in that particular detail.

Your criticism of the provided solution is correct.
When we say a train stops at a station at a certain number of minutes after the hour, we mean it stops at that time, allows passengers to board or alight from the train, and then immediately departs.
Whoever wrote this solution appears to have been thinking, "Each time train $X$ arrives (where $X$ can be A or B), it puts the station into condition $X$, during which new passengers take train $X$." But of course that's not how train stations work.
In other words, the solution seems to assume that "takes the first train" means "takes the last previous train" (usually an impossible task), whereas it actually means "takes the next train."
A person who arrives at $7$ minutes past the hour can be assumed to have missed the B train that arrived at $5$ minutes past the hour, so that person will take the A train that arrives at $12$ minutes past the hour.
Any other interpretation makes the given timetable useless.
(An objection might be made that in real life, if a train arrives exactly $5$ minutes past the hour and takes $30$ seconds to discharge and receive passengers, you have a chance to board it if you arrive on the platform at $5$ minutes $15$ seconds past the hour. The response to that objection is that this effectively shifts all last-chance-to-board times later by the same amount, so the probabilities are the same as if the schedule said the train departs at $5$ past rather than stops at $5$ past.)
The arrival times are:



Minutes past hour
Arriving train




$0$
A


$5$
B


$12$
A


$24$
A


$25$
B


$36$
A


$45$
B


$48$
A


$60$
A  (start of next hour)



So the next train is an A train from
$5$ to $24$ minutes, from $25$ to $36$ minutes, and from $45$ to $60$ minutes, a total of $45$ minutes.
